JpaRepository/PSQL: Count distinct on two columns ordered by date
I'm trying to get a count of results distinct by two columns using JpaRepository query. The distinct result needs to be the one with highest date, which I would then compare to current day to see, if it is in the past.
Let's say the table is movie_rental_deals and it has columns dvd_id and bluray_id, where one is always filled and other is always null. The table also has boolean rented and date return_time, which tell if the movie has been rented and when it will be returned. After renting, rented never changes to FALSE and another rental deal to the same movie will have a new row.
I want to get a count of all movies, which have at some point been rented (appear on the table and have rented = TRUE at least once), but are currently not rented (all of the movie's rented = TRUE rows have return_time in the past).
NOTE for table below: Today is 2024_05_07
| id | dvd_id | bluray_id  | rented | return_time |
| -- | ------ | ---------- | ------ | ----------- |
| 1  | 1      | NULL       | true   | 2024_01_01  | // dvd 1 rented and returned
| 2  | 1      | NULL       | true   | 2025_06_01  | // dvd 1 rented again, not returned
| 3  | NULL   | 1          | true   | 2024_01_01  | // br 1 rented and returned
| 4  | NULL   | 1          | false  | 2025_04_01  | // br 1 order data exists, not rented again
| 5  | 2      | NULL       | true   | 2024_01_01  | // dvd 2 rented and returned
| 6  | 3      | NULL       | false  | 2026_04_01  | // dvd 3 order data exists, never rented

Based on the table above, I should get a count of 2 (bluray-1 and dvd-2), since they've at some point been rented but are currently not in rental.
I've had trouble with distinct and the returning the data correctly. Getting distinct from multiple columns hasn't worked and I should also somehow get the max date for the order from the results that are TRUE. Any solutions to this?
One of my attempts below. Currently count and current date have not been included to the query, as I'm trying to just get the correct rows out of the repository call. Optimally I could return the count here, but I can use filtering and .size() later, if nothing else helps.
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT ON (mrd.dvd_id, mrd.bluray_id) mrd FROM MovieRentalDeal mrd " +
  "WHERE mrd.rented = true " +
  "ORDER BY mrd.dvd_id, mrd.bluray_id, mrd.return_time DESC")
List<MovieRentalDeal> findReturned();

--
EDIT 15.5.2024: I still haven't been able to add count and distinct to my query, but I've got the list out with all movie rentals that have at some point been rented and are currently not in rental.
Note that dvd and bluray are entity-connected, so I'm not using ids.
@Query("SELECT mrd FROM MovieRentalDeal mrd " +
    "LEFT JOIN FETCH mrd.dvd " +
    "LEFT JOIN FETCH mrd.bluray " +
    "WHERE mrd.rented = true " +
    "AND mrd.return_time < :date " +
    "AND (" +
      "(mrd.dvd IS NOT NULL AND mrd.dvd NOT IN (" +
        "SELECT mrd2.dvd FROM MovieRentalDeal mrd2 " +
        "WHERE mrd2.rented = true " +
        "AND mrd2.return_time > :date " +
        "AND mrd2.dvd IS NOT NULL" +
      ")) OR " +
      "(mrd.bluray IS NOT NULL AND mrd.bluray NOT IN (" +
        "SELECT mrd2.bluray FROM MovieRentalDeal mrd2 " +
        "WHERE mrd2.rented = true " +
        "AND mrd2.return_time > :date " +
        "AND mrd2.bluray IS NOT NULL" +
    ")))")
List<MovieRentalDeal> findReturned(Date date);

So now I only need to remove duplicate movies and count them, which I currently do in my service logic by using Set and then size(). This is good enough, but if someone can explain how I could add count and distinct to above query without errors, I'd gladly learn and add them.
Service logic:
int rentedCurrentlyReturnedMovies = dealRepository.findReturned(new Date())
    .stream().map(mrd -> 
        mrd.getDvd() != null 
            ? mrd.getDvd().getId() 
            : mrd.getBluray().getId())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet()).size();


Your query doesn't do what you want it to do. You only do a distinct. There is nou count nor max in there. Nor do I think that you should be returning the entity but rather a DTO with the result you want. Which is a count and a max date. If you want to count and a max date you would obviously need to express that in your query, which you don't.

I haven't got the query to return anything without exceptions yet, so that query was stripped down to add the count later. At this point I'm good with using .size() or anything to get it to work, if I could even return the entities.
But how do you mean I should do the DTO? Do you mean I should just return a List with id, rented and return_time and filter/distinct it afterwards? As I honestly in the end only need an Integer of the result, nothing more (so count would be optimal)

You stated you wanted a count and the max date that are 2 fields. Write the query you want, don't retrieve the content of your database and do the processing in memory. You got a database use it, write the query with a count in it.

Oh, I meant "results distinct by two columns and using the dates as the comparison on which to get". I worded that poorly, I'll clarify the question, sorry about that. In any case, I'm only interested in getting the total amount of movies previously rented and currently not rented.

Then write a query, which counts both true and false in different columns, then only select those rows with true > 0. You might even be able to using a HAVING clause in a SQL query.
